# pure css ribbon, the easy way?

Tags: css

I would like to achieve this ribbon using CSS3:

[image]

Is there a way to create "distorted" rectangles in CSS 3 or should I go for triangles? 
I'm pretty new to CSS3. What would be the easiest way to achieve this ribbon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some luck with this tool: http://cssarrowplease.com/

In your case, you will have both a `:before`, and an `:after` with different arrow configurations.

Lastly, note that to get a pointed arrow, you use a border on one side of 4.  But to get a diagonal line, you simply use a border on 2 adjacent sides, and no border on the other sides.

Good luck!

Comment: the solution was "skew":      -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);